# Virtual attribute is being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having some strange problem with virtual attributes in rails.

Here is my example model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates_presence_of :first_name

  def clean!
    first_name = nil
    last_name = nil
  end
end
```

I can then do:

```
user = User.first
user.last_name # => "Smith"
user.clean!
user.save # => true
user.first_name # => "Smith"
```

Right now the `first_name = nil` part is ignored.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: what if you type: `user.reload` before `user.first_name`?

Comment: why do you call this a virtual attribute? It doesn't appear to be.

Comment: I think you also have a typo in your question, you set last_name and then ask about first_name...  details details ... ;)

Comment: @apneadiving I removed to much of the original code. My first example contained some virtual attributes, but where a bit to complex for this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a virtual attribute, it's just a method.  It's not working because it doesn't know first_name is a method within the function, and thinks it is a variable.  use:

```
def clean!
  self.first_name = nil
  self.last_name = nil
end
```

A virtual attribute, OTOH, is like a new table column that can be assigned to:

```
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
end

def full_name=(name)
  split = name.split(' ', 2)
  self.first_name = split.first
  self.last_name = split.last
end
```

( virtual attribute code taken from http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes )